# How I can prevent the click event on a link which is nested on another element which also use onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, event-listener, dom-events

I have this simple code

```
<span class="doit"><a class="doit"href="ww.domain.com">text</a></span>
```

I want the click on the class "do it" fired a function, so I tried this

```
$(document).on('click', '.doit', function(e) {

    // prevents to handle the click for nested objects again
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert("hello world"); 
});
```

Now I have the problem, that if I click on the `<a href` the link from href will open and not the on.click function will be fired.

How I can prevent, that the link will be fired instead of the on.click event?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried a suggested answer with this, failed because the href link is already opened. I must prepare to open the link, only the on.click event should work.

```
<span class="doit">
 <a class="doit" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">webcms von 
  <span class="doit">ABC</span>
  <span class="doit">123</span>
 </a>
</span>
```

```
if ($(e.target).is("a")) {     
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the href 
    alert("I WILLL not go to " + e.target.href);
    e.cancelBubble = true; // do not click through
    e.stopPropagation(); // just stop the event or it will trigger again on the span
    return false; 
}

console.log('target:'+e.target);
```

In the console I read: [object HTMLSpanElement

I must find a way, which works in every way the html-tags are ordered or nested.

**Update 2**

```
if ($(e.target).is("a")) 
{     
      e.preventDefault(); // stop the href  
}
e.cancelBubble=true; // do not click through
e.stopPropagation(); // just stop the event or it will trigger again on the span
alert("hello world");
```

I see the alert 'hello world' but after that, the link will still be opened

Comment: Check [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test

However I do not recommend you give the same class to the two elements

Here you can click the link and the onclick of the span triggers but not the href

Nested spans are not correct HTML by the way

```js
$(document).on('click', '.doit', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("a")) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the href 
    alert("I WILLL not go to " + e.target.href);
  }
  e.cancelBubble=true; // do not click through
  e.stopPropagation(); // just stop the event or it will trigger again on the span
  alert("hello world");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="doit">
 <a class="doit" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">webcms von 
  <span class="doit">4U</span>
  <span class="doit">.tools</span>
 </a>
</span>
```

Alternative

```js
$(document)
  .on('click', 'a.doit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("I WILLL not go to " + e.target.href);
  })
  .on('click', 'span.doit', function(e) {
    alert("hello world");
    e.cancelBubble=true;  e.stopPropagation()
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="doit">
 <a class="doit" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">webcms von 
  <span class="doit">4U</span>
<span class="doit">.tools</span>
</a>
</span>
```

Comment: maybe there is a way to "disable" the link itselfs?

Comment: i've update my code with one of your suggestion, but it faild,please have a look - thanks a lot.

Comment: it ssems that the click not reach the on.click event, try your snippet without the "Span "Text <span class="doit"><a href=",,,,

Comment: thanks but for me it wont work, i've update my code again, could you have a look please?

Comment: You need to put the stopPropagation where you need it. Try the codes now

Comment: I've update the code again. I see the alertbox, but after that the link will open

Comment: oh please do me a favour and update the snippet, remove the part in the spans :-)

Comment: What part in which spans. You have 3 spans - nested spans  which is invalid HTML

Comment: may it helps to see my result in console "[object HTMLSpanElement"?

Comment: the last two spans

Comment: it seems that he trigger the click on to the span (4U - remove to ABC or something); so the event is calling but also he start the link from the parent a href

Comment: You cannot nest spans